Microsoft excel error when calloing another excel file
I am trying to open another Excel file from another Excel file.  I am using the following format to name the 2nd file:
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myfilename As String

myfilename = "C:\users\microsoft excel\sample.xlsm

I am getting a "400 error when I run this macro.  If I save the sample.xlsm file in c:\users folder, everything works, so it's most likely the SPACE in the string.  Is there anyway to incorporate the space in the string and avoid the 400 error?
I have tried:
myfilename = "C:\users\microsoft" & " " & "excel\sample.xlsm"

with the same 400 error result.

Please share the line of code that attempts to open the file.

To avoid having issues when you have spaces in your path, try using the Workbooks.Open function to open your Excel Files. Run the following Sub and your Excel File will open:
Sub OpenExcelFile()
   Dim myfilename As String

   myfilename = "C:\users\microsoft excel\sample.xlsm"
   Workbooks.Open myfilename
End Sub

If you also need to save this value into a variable, use the following Sub:
Sub OpenExcelFile()
   Dim myfilename As String

   myfilename = "C:\users\microsoft excel\sample.xlsm"
   Set file = Workbooks.Open(myfilename)
   ' The rest of your code...
End Sub

